# Check if duplicates of character sequence exists in a string - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know if any element of a string array is duplicated in a given string say:
    `var myArray = ["AB", "CD"];`
    `var givenString = "ABCDAB";`
        Here, the first element of myArray is repeated in the given string. I want to know(true/false) if this happened in the string. Should have true if any one element occurs more than once. Tried to use `new RegExp(myArray[0]).test(givenString)` but it only tests for a match nothing about the repetition.
         How can i do this ? I would be happy if i don't have to use flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map and indexOf

```
var s = "ABCDAB";
var check = ["AB", "CD"].map(function(e) { 
     return s.indexOf(e, s.indexOf(e) + 1) !== -1;
});
console.log(check.indexOf(true) !== -1);
```

---

What's happening - the map function passes each of the array elements to the function. Each of the array element then returns this

```
s.indexOf(e, s.indexOf(e) + 1) !== -1
```

The inner `s.indexOf(e)`, finds the location of the element inside our main string (s) and adds 1 to it (let's call this x). The outer `s.indexOf(` then searches for an instance of our element but it starts searching from position x, so it's effectively searching for the 2nd instance of our element (the 2nd parameter to indexOf indicates which position to start searching forward from).

If there is a 2nd instance we get the position (of this 2nd instance of the element), otherwise we get -1, which is effectively our check. If no instance of the string can be found the first indexOf returns -1 (this is equivalent to passing 0) and so does the 2nd instance (if there is no 1 instance there can't be 2 instances :-))

At the end of this map function we end up with an array of Boolean values indicating whether each of the elements occurs twice or not in s. The last line

```
check.indexOf(true) !== -1
```

basically checks if this array contains true i.e. if any of the elements occurs twice and you have your result.

Comment: It won't return the boolean requested in OP, but an array of booleans

Comment: good point. i misread part of it. made a small change. cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings This looks fine... i will accept this if you made your answer more clear. By the way nice username :D

Comment: @amanda014 thanks :-). I've updated the answer BUT I think Prashanth Chandra's answer is better (barring a small typo) or you could combine both `.some` and the above check now that you know how it works. My original answer was based on the assumption that you needed an array before Kaiido pointed out my mistake. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
checkDup(givenString, myArray) {
  return myArray.some(function(str) {
    if (givenString.indexOf(str) =! givenString.lastIndexOf(str)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
}
```

Regex should always be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If you `split()` your string on the requested values and that this value is duplicated, there must at least 3 parts.

```js
function checkDuplicate(arr, str){
  for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if(str.split(arr[i]).length>2) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
var myArray = ["AB", "CD"];
var givenString = "ABCDAB";
document.body.innerHTML = checkDuplicate(myArray, givenString);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>'+checkDuplicate(myArray, "ABCDBD")
```